# visualization of data from csv file

Tags: python, pandas

Good on everyone.
I have such a problem, I am looking for it and I do not find any answer.
Now I will present the data.

I have information about spaceships.
There is information about organizations, successful or failed flights.

I have grouped that data according to the successful flights, I have generalized the successful flights of ության 1 organization.

Now I want to visualize that data but it does not happen.

CODE:

````
y = new_fail_df[Status_Mission]
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()```


brings the following mistake։
KeyError: 'Success'

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnE6O.png
````

Comment: What you want to show and what kind of visualisation You are working on?

Comment: What is x? And where is  'Success' Key? (so philosophical...)

Comment: I work at matplotlib, I want to visualize the data of successful spaceship flights.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about you X column name but since you working with pandas DataFrame you can use
built-in function like df.plot

```
 new_fail_df.plot.scatter(x='your_x_column',

                          y='Status_Mission',)`
```

Comment: x The company name should be at the core.

Comment: When I post the name of the organization, it does not leave the following error.

KeyError: 'Company_Name'